# Inner Product Spaces : $N(T^{\star}\circ T) = N(T)$ (A PROOF)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, inner-products

Let $T$ be a linear operator on an inner product space. I really just want a hint as to how prove that $N(T^{\dagger}\circ T) = N(T)$, where "$^\dagger$" stands for the conjugate transpose.

---

Just as an aside, how should I read to myself the following symbolism:

[image]

Comment: What's $N$ mean?  Null space?

Comment: What's $N$? (I guess $T^*$ is the adjoint to $T$, right?)

Comment: Hint: If $T^*Tx=0$, what can you do to recover $\|Tx\|$?

Comment: Yes, it is adjoint. $N$ is null space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $V$ denote your inner product space. Clearly $N(T)\subseteq N(T^* T)$, so you really want to show that $N(T^* T)\subseteq N(T)$. Suppose $x\in N(T^* T)$. Then $T^* Tx = 0$, so we have $\langle T^* Tx, y\rangle = 0$ for all $y\in V$. Can you see where to go from here?